# What does "persecutory trends" imply in this definition?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I read a definition of the word "paranoid" in [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/paranoid) which was:

> characterized by suspiciousness, persecutory trends, or megalomania

I'm not sure what specifically "trends" mean above. Another definition of the word suggest that the one affected with paranoia feels as if other people are trying to harm them, but when I read the relevant definition of "trend" (which is "a prevailing tendency or inclination") it seems to suggest the person "does persecution" not "feel persecuted". What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Persecutory trends, in this case, mean **obtrusive ideas** -

## [Obtrusive idea](https://psychologydictionary.org/obtrusive-idea/)

> An obsessive, undesired, and foreign concept that intrudes upon an individual.

Comment: @KillingTime Done, sorry, I'm new to the resource.

Comment: If you have commenting privileges, you may use comments for this. This doesn't make for an answer.